# DropDown-Menu should stay opend after onClick

Tags: html, css, nav

My Homepage-Menu-Point "Software" should stay opened if you click on it!

See on my [Test-Homepage](http://test.guger.bplaced.net)!

I've tested to add "li:focus" and "li:active" to my lowermost CSS-Tag, but nothing worked. I also tried it with jQuery, without success!

The HTML-Code:

```
<nav id="cNav">
    <div class="Nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">G</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Software</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="sw/android/">Android</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sw/windows/">Windows</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about/">&Uuml;ber</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The CSS-Code:

```
#cNav {
    background-color: rgb(5, 90, 160);

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    width: 100%;
}

.Nav {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22pt;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.Nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    position: relative;

    width: 100%;

    text-align: center;
}

.Nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;  
    position: relative;

    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;

    padding-top: 0.4em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.Nav ul li a {
    outline: 0;

    color: white;

    position: relative;

    text-decoration: none;

    transition: color 0.3s;
}

.Nav ul li a::after {
    position: absolute;

    top: 100%;

    left: 0;

    width: 100%;

    height: 4px;

    background: white;

    content: '';

    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;

    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;

    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);

    -moz-transform: translateY(10px);

    transform: translateY(10px);

    margin: 0;
}

.Nav ul li a:hover::after { 
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
}

.Nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    white-space: nowrap;        
    position: absolute;

    text-align: center;

    top: 100%;

    margin-left: -5.3em;
}

.Nav ul ul li {     
    background-color: rgb(5, 90, 160);      
    border-top: medium solid rgba(0,115,209,1.00);

    margin-right: -1em;
}

.Nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You will need to change to class/css of it with JavaScript

Comment: Okey, I've really less experience with JS, do you have an example for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your Homepage-Menu-Point "Software" staying opened if you click on it, and you want to use jQuery, this might be a possible solution:

Add an id to the li with software:

```
<li id="software"><a href="/">Software</a>
```

Then you can use this to set the css display property of the ul to block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#software ul").click(function() {
        $(this).css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#software ul").click(function() {
    $(this).css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```css
#cNav {
    background-color: rgb(5, 90, 160);

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    width: 100%;
}

.Nav {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22pt;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.Nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    position: relative;

    width: 100%;

    text-align: center;
}

.Nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;  
    position: relative;

    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;

    padding-top: 0.4em;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.Nav ul li a {
    outline: 0;

    color: white;

    position: relative;

    text-decoration: none;

    transition: color 0.3s;
}

.Nav ul li a::after {
    position: absolute;

    top: 100%;

    left: 0;

    width: 100%;

    height: 4px;

    background: white;

    content: '';

    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;

    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;

    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);

    -moz-transform: translateY(10px);

    transform: translateY(10px);

    margin: 0;
}

.Nav ul li a:hover::after { 
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
}

.Nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    white-space: nowrap;        
    position: absolute;

    text-align: center;

    top: 100%;

    margin-left: -5.3em;
}

.Nav ul ul li {     
    background-color: rgb(5, 90, 160);      
    border-top: medium solid rgba(0,115,209,1.00);

    margin-right: -1em;
}

.Nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="cNav">
    <div class="Nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">G</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li id="software"><a href="/">Software</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="sw/android/">Android</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sw/windows/">Windows</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about/">&Uuml;ber</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks but my homepage doesn't react on the "Click", so the Code doesn't work and I don't know why!

Comment: @D4N1 I've added a code snippet in my answer.
Do you see error messages in the browser console when you load your homepage? Did you add jquery? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I don't know where the mistake is! Please look at it on [the Website](http://test.guger.bplaced.net)!

Comment: @D4N1 It seems to me like it works. I hover "Software" in the menu and then I see two items "Android" and "Windows". When I then click in the blue expanded area (not on "Android" or "Windows") and I hover away from the blue expanded area it stays visible.

Comment: ah okey... that was my error... I clicked on "Software"!

Thanks for the help!